# Android Studio to SQL Server - the SQL data is not displaying

Tags: android, sql-server

```
package com.example.connectandroid_sql;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class ConnectionHelper {
String uName, pass, iP, port, database;
@SuppressLint("NewAPI") //This syntax will be able to stop the app from crashing

    public Connection connectionClass() {
        iP = "136.158.28.124";
        database = "ExperimentTable";
        uName = "sa";
        pass = "admin";
        port = "1433";
    
        Connection connection = null;
        String ConnectionURL = null;
    
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    
        try{
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            ConnectionURL = "jdbc;jtds:sqlserver://" + iP + ":" + port
                    + ";" + "databasename =" + database + ";user=" + uName
                    + ";password= " + pass+ ";";
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionURL);
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            Log.e("Error",ex.getMessage());
        }
        return connection;
    }

}
```

The SQL data is not displaying, the error I kept receiving is the

> "E/Error: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver")

Here is my Connector Syntax

```
package com.example.connectandroid_sql;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Connection connect;
    String ConnectionResult ="";
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void getTextFromSQL(View v){
        TextView tx1 = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        TextView tx2 = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    
        try{
            ConnectionHelper connectionHelper = new ConnectionHelper();
            connect = connectionHelper.connectionClass();
            if (connect != null){
                String query = "Select * from ExperimentTable";
                Statement st = connect.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
    
                while (rs.next()){
                    tx1.setText(rs.getString(2));
                    tx2.setText(rs.getString(3));
                }
            }
            else{
                ConnectionResult = "Check Connection";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            Log.e("Error", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

I did create a new port "1433", I did install an older version of the JDBC Driver.
There are a few more errors that says

> Invalid File Path for libcolorx-loader.so

> E/Perf:  perftest packageName : com.example.connectandroid_sql App is allowed to use Hide APIs

But overall it runs all good, the only problem that I am encountering is that it does not display the data.

Comment: Aside... net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver hasn't received an update for nearly ten years, consider using the modern JDBC Driver (version) for SQL Server drivers from Microsoft.

Comment: Aside... you shouldn't be trying to access SQL Server directly from Android/iOS apps. Aside from the licensing and security problems of exposing your SQL Server to the open internet, the MS-TDS (Microsoft Tabular Data Streams) protocol was designed for LAN access and suffers horribly due to latency on the open internet - even more so with cellular/mobile networks where the client is constantly hopping between stations. Consider obfuscating your database behind a RESTful web service (or similar), allowing your clients to use the much better HTTP/HTTPS protocols for communications.